# Run Java program after exception encountered

Tags: java, file-io

How can I make my Java run again from the start (`main`) when it encounters an exception without closing and running it again manually?

My program basically writes on a file. When it cannot find the file I will throw the `FileNotFoundException` then write the file (say for example `hello.txt`). After it writes, the program closes (in NetBeans cause I am still developing it) and start showing this at the buttom:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at app4pics1word.App4pics1word.cache(App4pics1word.java:127)
    at app4pics1word.App4pics1word.<init>(App4pics1word.java:18)
    at app4pics1word.App4pics1word.main(App4pics1word.java:146)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: You could put a loop in `main` and catch any exceptions. Most of the time, that is not a very good solution, though. Seems to depend at least on the type of exception.

Comment: the variable you re using to write into the file is always null, that s why you have an exception. why do you want to run it after the exception occurs? anyway you can brute force it to run even with the exception. you can add a condition at the start that is always verified and it will start all over everytime.

Comment: can you provide the code that you're using ?

Comment: You should catch the exception and handle it (or prevent it in the first place). We can help if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //something wrong happens here
    }catch(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        main(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I like the recursive call for many cases where the amount of exceptions is expected to be small. I'm a bit reluctant to use it in `main` myself, though, as the unnecessary call frames will remain for the entire lifetime of the program.

Comment: @kviiri it gets more interesting if you also catch StackOverflowError, catching Throwable instead of Exception ;-)

Comment: @kviiri cannot find symbol `args`. BTW, in the main i call `cache();` In the `public int cache(){ i put the try-catch block here }`

Comment: @Leo, ooh, that's just devious ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use exception handling instead of restarting the program. If you restart the program, the error will still be there and thus your program will keep on trying to run for eternity, always failing with the same exception.

You would like to catch your exception and make sure that the input is valid:

```
boolean okInput = false;
int x = -1;
String someData = "rr";
do {
    try {
        x = Integer.parseInt(someData); // try to parse
        okInput = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException n) {
        // Error, try again
        okInput = false
        someData = "2";
    }
} while(!okInput); // Keep trying while input is not valid

// Here x is a valid number
```

[This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) provides you good code in general of how exceptions work.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
       boolean done = false;
       do {
         try {
          writeSomeFile();
          done = true;
         } 
         catch (Exception ex) 
         {
           System.out.println("Exception trapped "+ex)
         }
       } while (!done);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a loop that is broken only when the `try` block succeeds without an Exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            ...
            break; //at the end of try block
        } 
        catch (SomeException e) {
            //print error message here, or do whatever
        }
    }
    //program continues here once try block gets through w/o exceptions
    ...
}
```

However, instead of having this in your `main` I recommend hiding this rather ugly structure inside a method.